# Atom highlighting issue NBSP

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

Ok so for some reason my atom is highlighting random lengths of code on all my HTML pages after it reads past &NBSP, now this seemingly happened randomly out of the blue, one minute it was fine, the next I tabbed back to my Atom and this was the apparent issue, I've tried reinstalling twice removed all the hidden folders etc from users and alas still no luck.

I have attached a picture highlighting how it's colouring my HTML, & as previously mentioned this happens across the board on all my HTML pages and had no rhyme or reason to how much of my code it turns brown.

[image]

Comment: Can you write your OS and version number of your Atom?

Comment: Atom v1.22.0 x64 bit installer, OS is Win7 Enterprise

Answer (score 2):

`&` character entities are terminated by a semicolon. You have

```
&nbsp
```

But the proper character is

```
&nbsp;
```

So all that brown text is Atom waiting for the `;` to close the character entity.

This is not just a display issue in Atom. This will probably cause a rendering issue when this page is loaded, even if it just causes a useless `&nbsp` to appear in the page text.

Comment: Thank you very much this appears to have fixed the issue, still find it quite strange that it never highlighted this issue at the beginning & then seemingly randomly did. 

None the less thank you very much for the solution.